# Yii upload to local file path

Tags: php, file-upload, yii

I need to upload images to images path in my local site.. 
how can me write path ?

error:
$model->image->saveAs('/app/images');

images path
C:\xampp\htdocs\worldi\app\images

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
$images_path = realpath(Yii::app()->basePath . '/../images');
$model->image->saveAs($images_path . '/' . $model->image);
```

Answer (score 4):

Yii way of doing it will be using YiiBase::getPathOfAlias() which translate an alias to its corresponding path.
Yii predefine these alias

```
system: refers to the Yii framework directory;
zii: refers to the Zii library directory;
application: refers to the application's base directory;
webroot: refers to the directory containing the entry script file.
ext: refers to the directory containing all third-party extensions.
```

So using

> $imagePath = YiiBase::getPathOfAlias("webroot").'/images';

will give you required results.